# SQL ordering both negative and positive records in order issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a soccer stats table with the goal difference column having both positive and negative values.

| tmName | tmGroup | stsP | stsW | stsD | stsL | stsGF | stsGA | stsGD | stsPoints |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| team 1 | A | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 5 | 6 |
| team 2 | A | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 6 |
| team 3 | A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | -1 | 6 |
| team 4 | A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 6 | -5 | 6 |

I need to order the goal difference column in the table in order from highest to lowest like in the table sample above.

I have tried a couple of sql queries but not getting exactly what I need. I can't seem to get  the positive and negative values to order properly.

```
(SELECT stsID, tmName, tmGroup, stsP, stsW, stsD, stsL, stsGF, stsGA, stsGD, stsPoints 
FROM stats 
WHERE tmGroup='A' AND stsGD='0') 

UNION 

(SELECT stsID, tmName, tmGroup, stsP, stsW, stsD, stsL, stsGF, stsGA, stsGD, stsPoints 
FROM stats 
WHERE tmGroup='A' AND stsGD<'0' 
ORDER BY stsGD DESC, stsPoints DESC, stsGF DESC)

UNION 

(SELECT stsID, tmName, tmGroup, stsP, stsW, stsD, stsL, stsGF, stsGA, stsGD, stsPoints 
FROM stats 
WHERE tmGroup='A' AND stsGD>'0' 
ORDER BY stsGD ASC, stsPoints DESC, stsGF DESC)
```

With the above, the goal difference colunm (`stsGD`) gave me:

```
+5
-5
-1
+1
```

I modified the sql query as below:

```
SELECT stsID, tmName, tmGroup, stsP, stsW, stsD, stsL, stsGF, stsGA, stsGD, stsPoints 
FROM stats 
WHERE tmGroup='A' 
ORDER BY stsPoints DESC, stsGF DESC, stsGA ASC
```

With the above, the goal difference colunm (`stsGD`) gave me:

```
 +5  
 +1  
 -5  
 -1
```

I have tried using SIGN() function but still not the result I wanted.

```
SELECT stsID, tmName, tmGroup, stsP, stsW, stsD, stsL, stsGF, stsGA, stsGD, stsPoints 
FROM stats 
WHERE tmGroup='A' 
ORDER BY stsPoints DESC, SIGN(stsGD) DESC, stsGF DESC
```

With the above, the goal difference colunm (`stsGD`) gave me:

```
 +5  
 +1  
 -5  
 -1
```

I just can't seem to get the desired output.

Comment: Have one ORDER BY only,  at the end.

Comment: Try not to put all your code in a single line, it is hard to read like that

Comment: @jarlh if I use just one order by, I wont get the desired result becuase in a group table for soccer, it is arranged by points first and if 2 teams are on the same points, then goal difference comes in, then goals for and then goals against after.

Comment: A [mcve] would make things much clearer.

Comment: Your output makes no sense without any sample data, 4 comma-separated value bear no resemblance to the queries you have shown.

Comment: I will re-construct it now so it can be better understood

Comment: Is your value actually an integer, or is it a string? Your last two orderings make me think it isn't an integer and that you might be looking for `CAST(stsGD AS signed) DESC`

Comment: so how do you arrive at the value of *+5* for 'stsGD`, is this column a *varchar* column? (and if so, why?)

Comment: @stu the values are entered manually via a form and submitted into the database table. The page to view the table is where the query takes place to present it according to first points, then goal difference, goals for and goals agaisnt

Comment: sorry @Stu the stsGD column is a `varchar`column while stsPoints, stsGF and stsGA are `int` columns

Comment: Does `ORDER BY stsPoints DESC, CAST(stsGD AS signed) DESC, stsGF DESC, stsGA ASC` give you what you want?

Comment: Then you just need to `cast(stsGD AS signed)` to treat it as a signed integer for ordering?

Comment: @EdmCoff sorry I missed your first comment. Yes it orders as is required now.

Comment: @Stu Thanks also. CAST(stsGD AS signed) DESC works as is needed